# How to compare date only without comparing time in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, angular, sequelize.js

I have two columns called "DateStart" and "DateEnd" in the DB. Both have the following time format:

```
2023-04-03 09:00:00
```

When I do **POST** call, the JSON input looks like:

```
{
   DateStart: '2023-04-03 09:00',
   DateEnd: '2023-04-09 18:00'
}
```

I want to compare **only** date and find all data without comparing time.

My code in Sequelize looks like:

```js
function findDataMatch(data){
  const result = Model.findAll({
    where: {
      DateStart: data.DateStart,
      DateEnd: data.DateEnd
    }
  });

  return result.toJSON();
}
```

The above finds the data only if both date and time are exactly the same.

However, my expectation is:

When a user inputs the **same** date and **different** time, still I want the Sequelize to find the data matching with the same date regardless of the time unmatch.

Is there any way to do so? Please advice me.